# IE7 has issues displaying content from dynamically generated url in <object>

Tags: html, pdf, object, browser, internet-explorer-7

IE7 fails to display any contents in dynamically generated url inside the <object> element. Here's an example for loading pdf documents:

```
<object data="http://localhost:8080/Documents/Query?Id=document123&Session=1510" width="600" height="400"></object>
```

The above code will fail to load, however, if I copy and paste the url into the browser's navigation bar, the pdf document will load just fine. If I then manually save the pdf file and replace the object tag with the code below, it works just fine.

```
<object data="document123.pdf" width="600" height="400"></object>
```

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure exactly what the problem is without knowing more about your development platform and possibly seeing some of the code for `Query`. But my guess is that it's down to the mime type that the server is presenting.

You should send the mime type header as `application/pdf`.

Comment: As far as the Query goes, it's a java servlet. Which is configured correctly to set the content-type of the header. However, your answer got me thinking. I wanted to force IE7 to a particular mime-type. I then used <object data="..." type="application/pdf"></object> and it worked! So, it's either a bug or a intentional behavior of IE7 to look at the file name extensions to set the content type. It does not know how to read ahead from the server and set the type.

Comment: Now the only problem is, I need to make it dynamic for different content types. But that's a completely separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just came accross this issue myself.

I don't know if yours was the same problem as mine but if you are using the following:

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=...

Remove it, keep the content-type as "application/pdf" but don't assign a disposition, that way it will be processed as an outright file and not as an attachment to be downloaded.